# Assigning Fields of different data types dynamically in Apex

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have got a Map,in which i got a custom Field Name and API Name. I have written a for() loop of the above Map Keyset values. Here, the map contains Date Fields too. I getting an VF error for those Fields.

Ex:

```
Map<string,String> map1 = new Map<string,string>();
map1.put('custom Name','Name');
map1.put('custom Birthdate','Birthdate');

Map<string,String> FieldValues = new Map<string,string>();
FieldValues.put('custom Name','XYZABC');
FieldValues.put('custom Birthdate','26/08/200');

contact c = new contact();
for(string s : map1.Keyset()){
c.put(map1.get(s),FieldValues.get(s));
}
insert c;
```

While executing the Birthdate, i'm getting an error states ILLEGAL ASSIGNMENT since Birthdate is a Date Field and Map is a string data types.

Is there a way to handle it?

Comment: What is 'add' method?? This is invalid code...elaborate please about the error aswell...

Comment: @NickCook I'm getting 'Illegal assignment from String to Datetime' Error

Comment: @SanTosh Updated the code. Sorry for wrong typos.

Answer (score 2):

Representing various data types as a strings is full of awkward conversion issues. Better to keep the correct data type by using the base type `Object` for the map values and adding typed values:

```
Map<string, object> FieldValues = new Map<string, object>();
FieldValues.put('custom Name', 'XYZABC');
FieldValues.put('custom Birthdate', Date.newInstance(2000, 8, 26));
```

which will then allow the assignment to just work as the data is already of the correct type:

```
contact c = new contact();
for(string label : map1.Keyset()){
    c.put(map1.get(label), FieldValues.get(label));
}
insert c;
```